Component located at root of routing tree
I have 2 types of users : OWNER and CUSTOMER.
I am trying to create a module with 3 paths :

/owner : loads the owner sign-up module
/customer : loads the customer sign-up module
/ : displays a choice screen where the user will have to choose between the 2 paths

Here is the routing module :
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(
      [
        {
          path: "owner",
          loadChildren: () => import("./owner/sign-up-owner.module").then((m) => m.SignUpOwnerModule)
        },
        {
          path: "customer",
          loadChildren: () => import("./customer/sign-up-customer.module").then((m) => m.SignUpCustomerModule),
        },
        {
          path: "",
          component: SignUpComponent,
          pathMatch: "full"
        }
      ]
    )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SignUpRoutingModule {}

Children modules have this structure for routing :
@NgModule({
imports: [ 
  RouterModule.forChild(
    [
      {
        path: "",
        component: SignUpOwnerComponent,
        children: [
          { path: "step1", component: SignUpOwnerStep1Component },
          { path: "step2", component: SignUpOwnerStep2Component },
          { path: "step3", component: SignUpOwnerStep3Component },
          {
            path: "",
            redirectTo: "step1",
            pathMatch: "full",
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  )] })
export class SignUpOwnerModule {}

SignUpOwnerComponent is just a component containing a <router-outlet> + a "help" button that I want to be available at every step
When the 3rd route is present, it always takes precedence on the others. If I navigate to /owner, the choice screen will still be displayed
If the 3rd route is absent, the 2 other routes work fine.
I tried :

Various combinations of path: "", path: "*", path: "**",
pathMatch: "full", pathMatch: "prefix" (also tried with no pathMatch)
Changing the order of the routes

Also, if I put the 3rd route on another path (e.g. "choice"), it works, but if I tried to redirect "" to "choice", I have the same problem again
I would like the 3rd route to be active only when the path is empty

please share the routing structure of the lazy loading routes, the problem is there
